# Why DingTalk makes MacBook Air (High Sierra) so hot with hight volume fan's sound

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, performance

I think the app ding talkis a Windows-based design and does not work properly with Mac OS. The same issue happens with MS word or PowerPoint.

- MacBook Air (7,2)
- High Sierra

Is there any solution for that to avoid Windows-based design apps not bothering the CPU so I can work with programs that behave like Apple apps and don’t cause fan noise?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Forgive the edit if I assumed you have some apps that are economical and other apps that are not. Since you only listed three apps, I assumed the system behaves well with other apps and you’re not looking for software recommendations and need to use the “hot” apps and [just throttle them](https://stclairsoft.com/AppTamer/index.html)